# Custom RxJava's Scheduler

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

**Context**

I'm having an issue right now and is that I'm duplicating Retrofit's HTTP requests.

In my App I have a main screen which displays a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePageAdapter`. My App's architecture It's a pretty common MVP, I'm using RxJava and Retrofit with the `RxJavaAdapterFactory` to convert the `Call` into `rx.Observables`

Looks like this:

[image]

`Page1Fragment` displays a list of post articles for several teams. The thing is that the server-side endpoint that I hit to get that list of articles doesn't provide the team associated to each article, It just provides the team id associated to each article.

So I have to do an `Observable.zip` between the method that hits the server-side endpoint for getting the articles list and the server-side endpoint that gets the team list, and then I merge them.

`Page3Fragment` displays a list of all the user's teams (provided by the same endpoint that I used before)

**Issue**

The issue here is that as soon I open the App the 3 fragments are instantiated, and both the `Page1Fragment` and the `Page2Fragment` are hitting the team's endpoint to get the user's team list.

My question is; Is there a way to implement something like a custom Scheduler, attach it to the Retrofit's methods and avoid this kind of stuff?. Doing some validation like "Okay if N different subscribers are trying to get into this Retrofit Observable, return the same response for all of them" instead of hitting N times the server-side API. I'm currently using the Scheduler.io() to pass the .subscribeOn method.

Please, let me know if there's something not quite clear with this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a schedule so much as a way to manage access to the end points. Each request to a server should result in an observable, that will eventually provide the result.

```
Map<TeamId, Observable<Team>> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Requests are mapped to an observable that will eventually have a value emitted for it.

```
Observable<Team> lookUpTeam( TeamId id ) {
  return results.compute( id, (id, res) -> 
        res == null ? makeApiRequest( id ) : res );
}
Observable<Team> makeApiRequest( TeamId id ) {
  BehaviorSubject<Team> team = BehaviorSubject.create();
  teamServer.getTeam( id )
    .subscribe( team );
  return team;
}
```

The cache for team lookups is now held in a concurrent hash map that holds the last returned value. Only one API request will be made per team ID.

Comment: This is a good approach and gives me some ideas, but I was wondering if I could make something like this, but invalidate the cache after 2 seconds. I mean the team's information could change in the server-side, I don't want to keep returning the same response all the time.

Comment: You could easily add an operator that fired 2 seconds after the result was obtained that removed the subject from the map. Again, make sure to remove thread-safe operations, such as `removeIf()`.

Answer (score 0):

### Unique custom Scheduler with a Unique Thread (is different than Schedulers.single())

```
class SingleTask : Callable<Scheduler?> {
        @Throws(Exception::class)
        override fun call(): Scheduler {
            return SingleScheduler()
        }
    }


val newCustomScheduler : Scheduler = RxJavaPlugins.initSingleScheduler(SingleTask())

fun f() {
Completable.fromAction {
            // Do an Action here
        }.subscribeOn(newCustomScheduler).subscribe()
}
```

The result is like this:

- execute f()
- execute again f()
- execute again f()

first execution will handle the Action on Thread XYZ
second execution will handle the Action on Thread XYZ
third execution will handle the Action on Thread XYZ

So all will be executed on same thread.

In case you don't want to use Schedulers.single() which is kind of MainThread principle and is global scope defined on Schedulers class.